# My transition is not working on one of my elements

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a simple set up with some cartoon characters, and it seems like whatever I try to do with my transition code to the 'tom' element it wont affect it. My transitions work on one of two elements, but i can't get it to work on the last one. I'm realtive new to coding, so dont be too harsh on my coding.
Short story, I just want to add some transition to the element 'tom'.

I've tried to change up the transition property, duration, timing function and delay, to different values.

```css
#container {
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 650px;
  border: 2px solid rgb(0, 150, 150);
  background-color: rgb(0, 180, 200);
  overflow: hidden;
}

#jerry {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  left: -20px;
  bottom: 0px;
  transform: scaleX(-1);
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition-property: left;
  transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}

#tom {
  position: absolute;
  height: 150px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: -150px;
  transition-property: left;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

#container:hover #tom {
  right: 300px;
}

#container:active #jerry {
  left: -150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img id="jerry" src="images/jerry.png" alt="jerry">
  <img id="tom" src="images/tom.png" alt="tom">
</div>
```

Comment: any reason you use *hover* for one and *active* for the other? both should be *hover*

Comment: Not any specific reason. I tried changing it just for the purpose of trying to solve it. Changing both to hover, doesnt make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set `tom`'s `transition-property` to `left`, while changing its `right` property. Set the `transition-property` to `right`:

```css
#container {
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 650px;
  border: 2px solid rgb(0, 150, 150);
  background-color: rgb(0, 180, 200);
  overflow: hidden;
}

#jerry {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  left: -20px;
  bottom: 0px;
  transform: scaleX(-1);
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition-property: left;
  transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}

#tom {
  position: absolute;
  height: 150px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: -150px;
  transition-property: right;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

#container:hover #tom {
  right: 300px;
}

#container:active #jerry {
  left: -150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img id="jerry" src="images/jerry.png" alt="jerry">
  <img id="tom" src="images/tom.png" alt="tom">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace the below css code with your css.

```
#container {
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 650px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(0, 150, 150);
    background-color: rgb(0, 180, 200);
    overflow: hidden;
}

#jerry{
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
    left: -20px;
    bottom: 0px;
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    transition-timing-function: linear;
    transition-property: left;
    transition-delay: 0s;
    transition-duration: 1s;
}
#tom{
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: -20px;
  transform: scaleX(-1);
    transition-property: right;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-timing-function: linear;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}
#container:hover #tom{
    right: -150px;
}
#container:hover #jerry{
    left: -150px;
}
```